# Problem executing "minikube start" command

Tags: linux, shell, kubernetes, terminal, minikube

```sh
malik@malik:~$ minikube start
  minikube v1.12.0 on Ubuntu 18.04
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  minikube 1.12.1 is available! Download it: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.12.1
  To disable this notice, run: 'minikube config set WantUpdateNotification false'

  Pulling base image ...
  Downloading Kubernetes v1.18.3 preload ...
E0727 07:25:35.757871   14015 cache.go:63] save image to file "k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.18.3" -> "/home/malik/.minikube/cache/images/k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver_v1.18.3" failed: write: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/kube-apiserver/blobs/sha256:83b4483280e5187b2801b449338d5755e5874ab80c44bf1ce615d258142e7c8b: dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io: no such host
E0727 07:25:35.757643   14015 cache.go:63] save image to file "k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.7" -> "/home/malik/.minikube/cache/images/k8s.gcr.io/coredns_1.6.7" failed: write: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/coredns/blobs/sha256:c6568d217a0023041ef9f729e8836b19f863bcdb612bb3a329ebc165539f5a80: dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io: no such host
E0727 07:25:35.757512   14015 cache.go:63] save image to file "k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.18.3" -> "/home/malik/.minikube/cache/images/k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler_v1.18.3" failed: write: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/kube-scheduler/blobs/sha256:83b4483280e5187b2801b449338d5755e5874ab80c44bf1ce615d258142e7c8b: dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io: no such host
E0727 07:26:22.529729   14015 cache.go:63] save image to file "kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.1" -> "/home/malik/.minikube/cache/images/kubernetesui/dashboard_v2.0.1" failed: nil image for kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.1: Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io: no such host
E0727 07:26:22.544151   14015 cache.go:63] save image to file "kubernetesui/metrics-scraper:v1.0.4" -> "/home/malik/.minikube/cache/images/kubernetesui/metrics-scraper_v1.0.4" failed: nil image for kubernetesui/metrics-scraper:v1.0.4: Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io: no such host
E0727 07:26:22.579102   14015 cache.go:63] save image to file "k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.3-0" -> "/home/malik/.minikube/cache/images/k8s.gcr.io/etcd_3.4.3-0" failed: write: error calculating manifest: Get https://storage.googleapis.com/eu.artifacts.k8s-artifacts-prod.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:303ce5db0e90dab1c5728ec70d21091201a23cdf8aeca70ab54943bbaaf0833f: dial tcp: lookup storage.googleapis.com: no such host
E0727 07:26:22.579102   14015 cache.go:63] save image to file "k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.18.3" -> "/home/malik/.minikube/cache/images/k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager_v1.18.3" failed: write: error calculating manifest: Get https://storage.googleapis.com/eu.artifacts.k8s-artifacts-prod.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:da26705ccb4b5eb623a7cc42e566d21b0e23c1f59a0b4d6acac3fb810538c0d5: dial tcp: lookup storage.googleapis.com: no such host
E0727 07:26:22.579194   14015 cache.go:63] save image to file "k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.18.3" -> "/home/malik/.minikube/cache/images/k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy_v1.18.3" failed: write: error calculating manifest: Get https://storage.googleapis.com/eu.artifacts.k8s-artifacts-prod.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:3439b7546f29bec22edd737bc0a5770ead18b5ee5ce0aea5af9047a554715f9f: dial tcp: lookup storage.googleapis.com: no such host
E0727 07:26:22.579229   14015 cache.go:63] save image to file "gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v1.8.1" -> "/home/malik/.minikube/cache/images/gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner_v1.8.1" failed: write: error calculating manifest: Get https://storage.googleapis.com/artifacts.k8s-minikube.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:4689081edb103a9e8174bf23a255bfbe0b2d9ed82edc907abab6989d1c60f02c: dial tcp: lookup storage.googleapis.com: no such host
E0727 07:26:22.619544   14015 cache.go:172] Error downloading kic artifacts:  failed to download kic base image or any fallback image
❗  Executing "docker container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}" took an unusually long time: 5.369799649s
  Restarting the docker service may improve performance.
  docker "minikube" container is missing, will recreate.
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: recreate: creating host: create: creating: create kic node: create container: docker run -d -t --privileged --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --tmpfs /tmp --tmpfs /run -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro --hostname minikube --name minikube --label created_by.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=true --label name.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --label role.minikube.sigs.k8s.io= --label mode.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --volume minikube:/var --security-opt apparmor=unconfined --cpus=2 --memory=2200mb -e container=docker --expose 8443 --publish=127.0.0.1::8443 --publish=127.0.0.1::22 --publish=127.0.0.1::2376 --publish=127.0.0.1::5000 gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.10@sha256:f58e0c4662bac8a9b5dda7984b185bad8502ade5d9fa364bf2755d636ab51438: exit status 125
stdout:

stderr:
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.10@sha256:f58e0c4662bac8a9b5dda7984b185bad8502ade5d9fa364bf2755d636ab51438' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v2/k8s-minikube/kicbase/manifests/sha256:f58e0c4662bac8a9b5dda7984b185bad8502ade5d9fa364bf2755d636ab51438: Get https://gcr.io/v2/token?scope=repository%3Ak8s-minikube%2Fkicbase%3Apull&service=gcr.io: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.

  docker "minikube" container is missing, will recreate.
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
  Failed to start docker container. "minikube start" may fix it: recreate: creating host: create: creating: create kic node: create container: docker run -d -t --privileged --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --tmpfs /tmp --tmpfs /run -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro --hostname minikube --name minikube --label created_by.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=true --label name.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --label role.minikube.sigs.k8s.io= --label mode.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --volume minikube:/var --security-opt apparmor=unconfined --cpus=2 --memory=2200mb -e container=docker --expose 8443 --publish=127.0.0.1::8443 --publish=127.0.0.1::22 --publish=127.0.0.1::2376 --publish=127.0.0.1::5000 gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.10@sha256:f58e0c4662bac8a9b5dda7984b185bad8502ade5d9fa364bf2755d636ab51438: exit status 125
stdout:

stderr:
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.10@sha256:f58e0c4662bac8a9b5dda7984b185bad8502ade5d9fa364bf2755d636ab51438' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup gcr.io: no such host.
See 'docker run --help'.


❌  [INVALID_PROXY_HOSTNAME] error provisioning host Failed to start host: recreate: creating host: create: creating: create kic node: create container: docker run -d -t --privileged --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --tmpfs /tmp --tmpfs /run -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro --hostname minikube --name minikube --label created_by.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=true --label name.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --label role.minikube.sigs.k8s.io= --label mode.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --volume minikube:/var --security-opt apparmor=unconfined --cpus=2 --memory=2200mb -e container=docker --expose 8443 --publish=127.0.0.1::8443 --publish=127.0.0.1::22 --publish=127.0.0.1::2376 --publish=127.0.0.1::5000 gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.10@sha256:f58e0c4662bac8a9b5dda7984b185bad8502ade5d9fa364bf2755d636ab51438: exit status 125
stdout:

stderr:
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.10@sha256:f58e0c4662bac8a9b5dda7984b185bad8502ade5d9fa364bf2755d636ab51438' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup gcr.io: no such host.
See 'docker run --help'.

  Suggestion: Verify that your HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables are set correctly.
  Documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/
```

When I run the "minikube start" command the Docker fails to load the images that are needed as it is being used as the virtual machine manager by Minikube and Kubectl is providing the interface for Minikube to be used on the terminal. I executed commands and operations using the Virtualbox as well but no use. The version of Docker, Kubectl & Minikube is up-to-date.

**I have tried installing Minikube and Kubectl several times using different packages and methods but useless**
**Please help me so that I can be able to start a cluster and make my PC a Worker Node and get going on the road of Cloud Computing Development**

Comment: If you are connecting from China, Iran the issue is related to sanctions, regulations, or similar issues. There is a similar issue that has been issued for [Kubernetes Github] in the following link (https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8997/)

Answer (score 35):

You might have a minikube VM that has an old version or/and minikube cannot connect to. You can try deleting the VM and/or wipe out `~/.minikube`

```sh
$ minikube delete
$ rm -rf ~/.minikube
```

If that doesn't work then you have a problem with VirtualBox. Uninstall/Re-install

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Deleting the ~/.minikube folder did the trick

Answer (score 0):

3 years ago, I spent a lot of time struggling with **minikube** even though it has been the official way to run kubernetes locally.

If you get stuck, i would suggest to have a [KinD](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind) cluster up in few seconds by just running this script:

```
kind_version="v0.8.1"
kind_bin_path=/usr/local/bin/kind

if [ ! -f ${kind_bin_path} ]; then
  curl -Lo ./kind "https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/dl/${kind_version}/kind-$(uname)-amd64"
  chmod +x ./kind
  sudo mv ./kind ${kind_bin_path}
fi



cat <<EOF | kind create cluster --config -                   
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
- role: worker
- role: worker
EOF

export KUBECONFIG="$(kind get kubeconfig-path --name="kind")"

# Now check 
kubectl get nodes

# Congrats!
```

To customize more the cluster, check [other YAML config here](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/).

Good luck for whatever works for you.